# Issue with loading an URL in iOS 6 (works fine in iOS 5)

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, ios6, uiwebviewdelegate

I am calling an urlRequest in my webview and it redirect to another url which works perfectly fine with iOS5 but in iOS6 it is just showing the blank page. It doesnt give any webview error and webviewFiniishedLoading method calls but just display the blank page..

My url format looks like this

https://wap.XXXXXXXX.com/api/en/game.html?page=cashier&username=XXXXX&temptoken=BD351080E4AC50A603462DFCB210C38C&successurl=mobileApp%3A%2F%2FdepositSuccess&native=1

is there anything wrong with the above url.

note. XXXX is replaced for the actual values. Also this url works perfectly fine in iOS 5

Comment: are you setting any html tag to load the url?

Comment: nope. I am suspecting that content inside the mobile formatted webpage. did you ever had problems while making you desktop page into mobile page?

Comment: yes i had the issue long time back, which got resolved by usage of iframe as html tag instead of embedding the url, even in IOS 6 main thing that solved my issue was that i changed some parameters like i had url as : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxx?autoplay=1 which was not working , but as i changed it to :http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxx?autoplay=1 it worked for both ios 5 and 6.

Comment: I know the one you had. Apple mention that in ios 6 release notes that there is this change to the youtube embedded url. But i dont know what is going on wiht my url (may be content inside webpage)?